# android custom dialog error

Tags: android, customdialog

I'm trying to create a custom dialog and I'm having some trouble.

The custom dialog is to be shown after the user press the menu button and pick an option.

Here is the code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater myMenu = getMenuInflater();

        myMenu.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.email:

                Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.email);
                dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

                dialog.show();

                break;
            case R.id.info:
                // Todo something
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

And `R.layout.email` is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/emailTitle" />

    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/multiAutoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="4dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </MultiAutoCompleteTextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailTV1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/emailBsend"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/emailSend" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/emailBcancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/emailCancel" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emailTV2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use getApplicationContext. use

```
Context mContext = [ActivityName].this;
```